# How can i send a JSON variable as param in alamofire post request

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire, xcode8

```
Alamofire.request("https://test.com", method: .post, parameters: d, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
        .responseJSON { response in
        print(response)
    }
```

I am using the above method to send post request using Alamofire. Here "d" is the JSON variable. But an error comes saying extra arguement method in call. Why is it happening.

Comment: Add you json which you are sending as params.

Comment: "d" must not be a JSON variable!!! Must be a variable of type [String: Any]. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to send parameters like this:

```
let params: [String: Any] = [Key 1: value1, Key 2: value2]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct format.

> Parameters in your case **d** must be of type : **[String: Any]**

```
let d: [Sting: Any] = [
            "some key": some value,
            "some key": some value,
            ]

        Alamofire.request("url", method: .post, parameters: d)
            .validate()
            .responseJSON {
                (response) in
        }
```